# CDATA in JAXB inside CXF

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, cxf, cdata

I am writing a JAX-RS webservice . Which returns a Reponse back in form of application/xml .In that I have to produce CDATA sections . I have researched a lot and I have seen many blogs . But I am still not able to do so . I have tried following approaches:

1) Writing your own Jaxb2Marshaller as mentioned here : http://www.coderanch.com/t/584332/Web-Services/java/Spring-WS-JAXB-CDATA . And I have configured like below :

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="com.test.CdataJaxb2Marshaller">
<property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>
 <value>com.test.MyModel</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="cdataElements">
    <list>
        <value>Data</value>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

But I am not getting a call in marshall method of the CdataJaxb2Marshaller . I am wondering that I have configure the the marshaller inside the  or somewhere else . Could someone suggest .

2) The second approach I have tried is mentioned here : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201203.mbox/%3CCAEDT_BW49HTNZtad5P+GoGZLpLYTnEwO50dzUuPNKnpWsy=rdQ@mail.gmail.com%3E . But I doesn't talk about how to configure CdataWriterInterceptor inside 
I tried configuring as follows :

3) Third approach I tried is very similar to the the second , with the difference that instead of  Interceptor I configured a provider , something thats mentioned here :

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/systests/jaxrs/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/jaxrs/XmlStreamWriterProvider.java

I don't want to use some third party stuff like eclipse link Moxy . Alas JAXB natively doesn't support CDATA sections . It would be great help if someone has an anwser to this problem.

Thanks,
Aman.

Comment: Here is how it could be done with MOXy:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/cdata-cdata-run-run-data-run.html.

Comment: I want to avoid any outside libraries , could it not be done via a custom interceptor/provider/marshaller.